# Antlr string token without a certain character sequence

Tags: string, antlr4, lexer

I'm trying to define a lexer grammar that matches string tokens that don't contain a certain sequence of characters. For instance "AB"

Example of strings I want to capture

```
""

"asda A rewr A"

"asda A"

"asdas B ad"
```

but not

```
"asdas AB fdsdf"
```

I tried a few things but I always seem to miss some case

Comment: Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: You want to capture `"asda A rewr A"` as a single token? And how should `"asdas AB fdsdf"` then be tokenized if not as 1 token? Are the surrounding quotes also part of the token? Besides a bit more details, perhaps post your grammar too.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like that to be a single token. For the "... AB.. " case I have other rules afterwards, with lexer modes etc. But, I think that would be orthogonal. For this example, even disallowing "... AB ..." would suffice. Also, yes quotes are part of the token.

Comment: I ended up with the following which seems like it's replicating a few things so I'm wondering if I could do it better (or if I'm missing something)
`fragment P_NORMAL_STRING_ELEMENT: 'A' ~["\r\n\\B] | ~["\r\n\\A] | P_ESCAPE_SEQUENCE;`
and
`T_STATIC_STRING_LITERAL: '"' P_NORMAL_STRING_ELEMENT* 'A'? '"';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done with a little *mode magic*: when you're in the first *string-mode* and you encounter a `AB`, you just push into the second *string-mode*:

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;

QUOTE      : '"'        -> more, pushMode(MODE_1);
SPACES     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

mode MODE_1;
STR_1      : '"'        -> popMode;
AB         : 'AB'       -> more, pushMode(MODE_2);
CONTENTS_1 : ~["]       -> more;

mode MODE_2;
STR_2      : '"'        -> popMode, popMode;
CONTENTS_2 : ~["]+      -> more;
```

The Java demo:

```java
String source = "\"\"\n" +
    "\"asda A rewr A\"\n" +
    "\"asdas AB fdsdf\"\n" +
    "\"asda A\"\n" +
    "\"asdas B ad\"\n";

Lexer lexer = new MyLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

System.out.println(source);

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-20s `%s`%n",
      MyLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
      t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

will print the following:

```
""
"asda A rewr A"
"asdas AB fdsdf"
"asda A"
"asdas B ad"

STR_1                `""`
STR_1                `"asda A rewr A"`
STR_2                `"asdas AB fdsdf"`
STR_1                `"asda A"`
STR_1                `"asdas B ad"`
```